# Handle multiple similar requests in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, instagram

In my WebApi controller I have the following (pseudo) code that receives update notifications from [Instagrams real-time API](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/):

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(InstagramUpdate instagramUpdate)
{
    var subscriptionId = instagramUpdate.SubscriptionId;
    var lastUpdate = GetLastUpdate(subscriptionId);

    // To avoid breaking my Instagram request limit, do not fetch new images too often.
    if (lastUpdate.AddSeconds(5) < DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
        // More than 5 seconds ago since last update for this subscription. Get new images
        GetNewImagesFromInstagram(subscriptionId);
        UpdateLastUpdate(subscriptionId, DateTime.UtcNow);
    }
}
```

This won't work very well if I receive two update notifications for the same subscription almost simultaneously, since `lastUpdate` won't have been updated until after the first request has been processed.

What would be the best way to tackle this problem? I'm thinking of using some kind of cache, but I'm not sure how. Is there some kind of best practices for these kind of things? I'm guessing it's a common problem: *"receive notification, do something if something hasn't been done recently..."*

Comment: Does lastUpdate contain some kind of id, which could be used to check if that update is already received? If so put it into static variable and check against it always when update is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276847/asp-net-caching-strategy-pattern/276858#276858) I went with the following approach, using [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(IEnumerable<InstagramUpdate> instagramUpdates)
{
    foreach (var instagramUpdate in instagramUpdates)
    {
        if (WaitingToProcessSubscriptionUpdate(instagramUpdate.Subscription_id))
        {
            // Ongoing request, do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            // Process update
        }
    }
}

private bool WaitingToProcessSubscriptionUpdate(string subscriptionId)
{
    // Check in the in memory cache if this subscription is in queue to be processed. Add it otherwise
    var queuedRequest = _cache.AddOrGetExisting(subscriptionId, string.Empty, new CacheItemPolicy
    {
        // Automatically expire this item after 1 minute (if update failed for example)
        AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
    });

    return queuedRequest != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it is awful idea, but ... Maybe it worth to add lock to this method ? Like

```html
 private List<int> subscriptions = new List<int>();
```

and then

```html
 int subscriptinId = 1;//add calculation here
            int subscriptionIdIndex = subscriptions.IndexOf(subscriptinId);

            lock (subscriptions[subscriptionIdIndex])
            {
                //your method code
            }
```

*Feel free to criticize this approach )*

Comment: Yeah, I don't really wan't to lock anything. I would prefer having some kind of cache that is "global" to all requests, and that I can update quickly as soon as a get an update notification. And then I can use that to check if I should process the next notification.